# Keep 150 latest entries per user

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have a mysql table where I track user preferences. 
The table consists of a user_id, a name and a timestamp

(user_id, name is the PK)

If an entry already exists, I update the timestamp to the current time

Now, what I would like, is for the 150 most recent entries per user to be active.
Every time the user logins, I want to run the query to delete any entries that are to be deleted.

However, I cannot get my head around the delete query that achieves something like that.

Any help?

Comment: Why? Why would you delete anything? Why not just select 150 last entries and treat them as active?

Answer (score 1):

I edited the answer. I was telling you to delete the 150 most recent, that's not what you want.. Here's how to delete all other rows:

```
DELETE FROM preferences WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM preferences ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 150)
```

Comment: This also does not work. Mysql states that you cannot use the table being deleted in a subquery

Answer (score 0):

Followed the hack mentioned here
http://helphow.info/?qa=209695/solved-mysql-delete-from-limit-x-y-would-not

Basically, I created a temp table with all entries I wished to delete and then made a delete with an inner join

Worked perfectly

Comment: You do realize the implications of your (terrible) logic?

Comment: I am sure you can explain it for me?

Comment: `Now, what I would like, is for the 150 most recent entries per user to be active` - you achieve that by selecting last 150 records. You don't delete stuff in order to have 150 records active. That's bad approach in the logic. You use the database to store data, and using relations you obtain the data that's of interest to you. Implementing logic on database level (deleting records when certain condition is met) is always bad. Databases are meant to hold and manipulate data, not make logical decisions. However, it's your code and your db so you are free to do whatever you like.

Comment: And what is the purpose of storing entries that are of no use? Making queries slower? Eating up space and memory? I do not argue that a db is for storing data, but in this case there is no meaning in keeping them forever. It's bad to consider that the only use of a DB is for storing data indefinite. I would suggest to be more open minded.

Comment: What's the point of creating a questionable functionality by using temporary tables on every user-connect? It's bad approach. Also, I'll argue your statement about "eating up space" and performance. If you actually want to get rid of records or archive them, you do that periodically, using MySQL's event scheduler. While you don't have records deleted, you select last 150 records. Also, since MySQL can easily handler millions of rows on rather entry level machine, I doubt you'll feel any performance issues. I would suggest to read about MySQL's optimizations before making bold statements.